# how to parse a large tsv file with node and streams

Tags: node.js, csv, stream

I have retrieved a dump of IMDB data (thanks to http://www.omdbapi.com/ and a small donation) as a TSV file (containing 1,111,073 lines). Each line represents for a movie, and they look like this:

```
ID  imdbID  Title   Year    Rating  Runtime Genre   Released    Director    Writer  Cast    Metacritic  imdbRating  imdbVotes   Poster  Plot    FullPlot    Language    Country Awards  lastUpdated
1   tt0000001   Carmencita  1894    NOT RATED   1 min   Documentary, Short      William K.L. Dickson        Carmencita      5.8 1100    http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMjAzNDEwMzk3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwOTk4OTM5Ng@@._V1_SX300.jpg    Performing on what looks like a small wooden stage, wearing a dress with a hoop skirt and white high-heeled pumps, Carmencita does a dance with kicks and twirls, a smile always on her face.   Performing on what looks like a small wooden stage, wearing a dress with a hoop skirt and white high-heeled pumps, Carmencita does a dance with kicks and twirls, a smile always on her face.       USA     2015-12-10 01:09:33.043000000
```

My goal is to visualise the evolution of movie lengths over time. Therefore I nee to create two arrays, one for the min/max and one for the avg values for each year (because the Highcharts chart type "area and line chart" expects that format). So I've written a script that works OK for a small subset, but throws, not unexpectedly, an error when attempting to read the whole file.

I'm well aware that streams should be able to help with this, but my expertise is limited and this little project is actually there to help me grok streams better...

Here is the script as it currently stands:

https://gist.github.com/jfix/f79f011ce99d2049613c

If it is preferable to have the whole script shown inline in my question, I can obviously add it.

Here is the error that is thrown:

```
$ node each.js
buffer.js:382
    throw new Error('toString failed');
    ^

Error: toString failed
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:382:11)
    at StringDecoder.write (string_decoder.js:129:21)
    at Parser._transform (/Users/jakob/Projects/imdb-film-length/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:154:26)
    at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:292:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:278:5)
    at Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:207:11)
    at /Users/jakob/Projects/imdb-film-length/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:46:14
    at doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)
```

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating your situation and I get the same error just by running:

```
csv(file, {delimiter: tab, relax: true, columns: true}, (err, out) => { });
```

So it seems the csv-parse module makes the process run out of memory because the callback allocates a lot of arrays. You probably need to use the stream api for the csv-parse module instead. An example is described here: http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/examples/

Comment: Thanks @Mathias, I had a look at them but they didn't really seem to fit my problem, although that's probably my problem at not understanding them well enough. I'll give it another go.